# Vaadin - maximize changeable container width

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, vaadin, vaadin7

"leftContent" container in code below has fixed width (100px) and everything's ok with it. The question is: how to set mainContent's width to maximum? By maximum I mean fill all the browser's available width. For now I have scrollbar shown right next to buttons, which isn't what i've expected. I also don't wanna set fixed width in px for this 'mainContent" element.

Thanks in advance!

Main UI class:

```
protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {
    VerticalLayout leftContent = new VerticalLayout();
    [...]
    VerticalLayout mainContent = new VerticalLayout();
    mainContent.setSizeFull();
    mainContent.setMargin(false);

    HorizontalLayout container = new HorizontalLayout();
    container.addComponents(leftContent, mainContent);
    setContent(container);

    Navigator navigator = new Navigator(UI.getCurrent(), mainContent);
    [...]
}
```

MainView class:

```
public class MainView extends Panel implements View {

@Override
public void enter(ViewChangeEvent event) {
    setSizeUndefined();
    VerticalLayout verticalLayout = new VerticalLayout();
    verticalLayout.setSizeUndefined();
    for(int i=0;i< 30;i++) {
        verticalLayout.addComponent(new Button("text"));
    }
    setContent(verticalLayout);
    setSizeFull();
}
```

Comment: In your `init` method, did you try `container.setSizeFull()`?

Comment: Well it helped but leftContent expanded to 50% of screen width. I've tried setting `container.setExpandRadio(...)` but it cannot be permanent solution because when window gets smaller leftContent also shrinks. @Morfic Do you have any idea for that ?

Comment: Well, if you can provide a [sscce](http://sscce.org) and maybe a couple of screenshots explaining what you'd like to happen and what's currenlty wrong, we'll surely take a look a it. As it stands now, it's a bit difficult to figure out just from the description

Comment: Did you try `leftContent.setWidth("100px"); container.setExpandRatio(leftContent, 0f); container.setExpandRatio(mainContent, 1f);`? If so, what was the problem?

Comment: @A.Meier Worked like a charm, thank you! Despite all I must say that vaadin's official guide should contain more information about such basic behaviours...

Comment: That''s great. I wrote the answer down, so you can check it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For clarity this is the answer from the comment. The following code gives the main content the maximum width.

```
leftContent.setWidth("100px");
container.setExpandRatio(leftContent, 0f);
container.setExpandRatio(mainContent, 1f);
```